# Ubuntu not shutting down

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu for a week and since a few days it is no longer able to properly shut down the computer.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I have tried booting the old kernel and using the terminal (sudo shutdown -h now, sudo reboot) to shut down the computer, but to no luck.

Comment: Check all scripts run in the shutdown process for anything that looks like it would spawn an interactive shell. The "Userspace bootsplash" seems like a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Something is FUBAR in the startup/shutdown scripts. You could restore them using a simple Ubuntu live disk. Or just reinstall the system, and re-attach your home directory at install. (So your stuff won't "disappear".)

Comment: Yes, but that makes it my last Ubuntu experience (last year) all over again. In the 2 weeks I used Ubuntu, I had to reinstall the entire system twice and that's what people used as argument against Windows: Ubuntu doesn't require to reinstall. Also, I don't like the term FUBAR: It means just giving up and not learning.

Comment: Oh I very much tried back then. Like when I had to read my mails and Arch Linux refused to do so. I spent 4 hours, fixing things, so I can read my mail, and turn off my computer. I'm not saying you have to reinstall ... it's an easier alternative, a less time consuming one, that is. You CAN check your /etc/rc.*/ init scripts, diff them ( to the ones on the disc / .debs ) and then fix them by hand. It's just ... I jumped into an assumption, that you don't want to waste your time. :)

Comment: Also, check IRC when you encounter such a problem. We help here ... on SU, we try to do so. But getting help real-time on the #Ubuntu channel for example, is much faster. (Or get on the SU chat when it happens next time.)